# Why can't one of my Rails processes see what the other has committed to the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm developing an app on top of Amazon FPS. When you make a payment with FPS, the payment succeeds asynchronously: you make a request and wait for a POST (an Instant Payment Notification) informing you whether the charge completed.

I need the user to see whether the charge completed by the next page load (if possible), so I'm having the server:

1. Charge the user, then
2. Spin in a loop checking the database for a status update, and
3. Time out if it takes too long

Meanwhile, another server process is:

1. Receiving the IPN and
2. Noting the success in the database for the other process to see.

I'm running Unicorn with 3 workers. They're all logging to the same terminal window. I see the first process begin to spin, reporting repeatedly that the charge is still pending. Then I see the IPN come in, and the second process pick it up and write to the database that it has succeeded. Then I see the first process continue to see that it's pending.

Why does it never see the success value that was written to the database?

It feels to me like a transaction issue, so I ran a separate process which loops and outputs the status of the latest charge. When the second process reported that it marked the charge successful, this third independent process agreed. It's just the first server process that's failing to see the updated value.

As far as I can tell, the loop in that first process is not inside a transaction, and so it shouldn't be reading an old snapshot. But perhaps it is? How would I tell?

**My Stack**:

- Unicorn 4.6.3
- Rails 4.0
- Ruby 2.0
- Postgres 9.2

Comment: If the third process sees it, kind of sounds like the looping process is perhaps never hitting the database again, but instead is just pulling the old cached copy?  Maybe?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom's question must remain a "maybe" until we see this looping code.

Comment: The looping server process is running `puts "#{charge.id} still pending" if charge.reload.pending?` repeatedly. If it's cached, it's somewhere below ActiveRecord.